# Enable horizontal scroll bar in table in jqgrid

Tags: css, jqgrid, scrollbar

I am facing issue to enable horizontal scroll when grouping text does not fit in table width is present in jqgrid.

The table width is approx `50%` of the screen and grouping text length is `300 characters` after adding overflow property to the table no scroll bar is being added and text is getting hidden.

Highlight in the image line shows the problem
[image]

Comment: Share the HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Can't share the code but I have added the image for the probelm.

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow-y:scroll` in your `table` that should take care of that.

Set `shrinkToFit : false` or make your element set to above mentioned way.

```
<div style="width:100px;overflow:auto;"><table id="yourTable"></table><div>
```

You can use CSS for that.

```
yourTableSelector{
      width:50%;
      overflow-y:scroll;
       }
```

An example:

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  height:100px;
 width:50%;
 border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div>There are two different ways to make these divs scroll horizontally and which path you choose will probably come down to personal preference and/or browser support.
  There are two different ways to make these divs scroll horizontally and which path you choose will probably come down to personal preference and/or browser support.
  There are two different ways to make these divs scroll horizontally and which path you choose will probably come down to personal preference and/or browser support.</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the code changes are not working. I have added the image to singh my problem.

Comment: you mean `shrinkToFit : false` this didn't work for you or  using `overflow:auto`.

Comment: The problem here is that when grouping text overflow no scroll bar is added. I want a scroll bar for that case

Comment: I didn't get what that means, I can try to help you out if you can share a snippet.

Comment: I got the solution for the problem in the code. The **table-layout** property was set to fixed and I changed it to auto then the scroll bar was working.